# Displaying a UIActivityIndicatorView While Playing an AUGraph

Tags: ios, core-audio

My iOS app has 4 filePlayer units connected to a Mixer unit in an AUGraph. I want the user to be able to email the "mix" of the four filePlayer units as one .caf file.

I'm capturing the output of the mixer by attaching a callback to the remoteIO and in the callback writing the output of the mixer to a file via ExtAudioFileWriteAsync.

I kick off that process - that is to say I call `AUGraphStart` - when the user clicks on my "Export Mix and Email" button. Since `AUGraphStart` happens on a different thread, my app next calls the `MFMailComposeViewController` code while the graph is running. This code displays the email form and attaches the mixed .caf file to the email. The obvious problem here being that the file, while created, isn't completely written since the graph is still running.

To work around this, right after kicking off the start of the AUGraph I do this:

```
    while ([myMixerObject graphIsRunning]) {
//        NSLog(@"...waiting for graph to stop...");
    }
```

`graphIsRunning` simply calls `AUGraphIsRunning` and returns a Boolean.

This worked, despite seeming slipshod, but I kept going.

Things became more concerning when I tried to display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` while the AUGraph was capturing the output of the mixer. In short, when I do this...

```
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    while ([myMixerObject graphIsRunning]) {
//        NSLog(@"...waiting for graph to stop...");
    }
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

...the indicator never appears.

Just for kicks I put `[activityIndicator startAnimating]` inside the while loop, but it still doesn't appear.

I've checked that the activityIndicator object is being instantiated correctly (e.g. I can make it appear when the graph isn't running) so it leads me to believe there's something special about calling it while the `AUGraph` is running.

I'm still new to iOS and Core Audio but I know that some Core Audio calls happen on a real-time thread, so my first suspicion is that there's some concurrency issue going on. However I have no idea where to start. Is my `while()` loop where the troubles begin? Should I be approaching that differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop is blocking the main thread which is why you are experiencing UI issues.  Rather than polling your mixer object I recommend registering a callback (using `NSTimer` or a GCD timer) that is called periodically (5-10 times per second).  This callback should check whether the mixer graph is running.  Once the graph has stopped, your timer callback can handle the necessary UI changes and cleanup.